# `dbt run --select x` gives error `Could not find selector named x, expected one of []`

Tags: dbt

Using dbt 0.20.x and below, the command `dbt run --select model_name` fails.

It shows the error `Runtime Error. Could not find selector named model_name, expected one of [] Code: 10001`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dbt 0.21.0, the node selection syntax was [standardised](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/pull/3791) to use `--select` everywhere. Before this, some commands like `dbt run` and `dbt test` used `--models` instead.

Older versions show the error because [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#allow-abbrev) is expanding `--select` to `--selector`, a different flag.

To fix this issue, either upgrade to dbt 0.21.0 or higher or use `--models` instead of `--select`.